# Spring Securitiy's check login returns always to index

Tags: spring, jsp, authentication, spring-security, admin

I'm developing a web application in Java using Spring MVC and Spring Security. Actually I have defined two roles: ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN, but login doesn't work:

When I insert correct data I'm redirected to index.jsp, even if I expected to be redirected to utenti/lavoro.jsp if I use user's credentials or to amministrazione/homeAdmin.jsp if I use admin's credentials.

Where am I wrong?

**spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/error" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/utente**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/login"  />
    </http>
<authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
      <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
          <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
     users-by-username-query="select username,password,TRUE from Utente where username = ?" 
     authorities-by-username-query="select username,role from Utente where username = ?"  />
     </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
  <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/trascrizioni" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="postgres" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Trascrizioni Medievali</title>


</head>

<body>

        <center>Login</center>

    <form method="POST" name="f" action="<c:url value="/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check"/>">
            <div align="center">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type='text' name='j_username' /><br>

            <label>Password</label>
            <input type='password' name='j_password'><br>

            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
            </div>
        </form>


          <center><a style="color: red" href="registrazione"> Registrate</a></center>
         <center> <h4><a href="index">BackToHome</a></h4></center>
</body>
</html>
```

**amministrazione/homeAdmin.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Trascrizioni Medievali</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>Hello, ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**utenti/lavoro.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Trascrizioni Medievali</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <strong>Welcome</strong><td>${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}</td>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ControllerLogin**

```
package trascrizione.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import trascrizione.model.Utente;

@Controller
public class ControllerLogin {

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginAdmin() {
        return "amministrazione/homeAdmin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/utente**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginUtente() {
        return "utenti/lavoro";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login (ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new Utente());
        return "login";

    }


}
```

Comment: in your spring security xml set the default-target-url to where you want to redirect to on a successful login.

Comment: what url can I set?

Comment: the url to the page you want displayed after a successful login. /utenti/lavoro.jsp

Comment: or set it the url to the appropriate @RequestMapping in your controller

Comment: I just reread your post and it looks like you want to redirect to different jsp based on the users role.   You can map the default-target-url to the controller mapping and inside the mapped method you can get the user role and return the string of the appropriate jsp based on the role.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986362/spring-security-redirect-based-on-role

Comment: Thanks. With Your Solution I Solved the Problem